# Getting accountname, cards and totalamount from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
     Account / Card  Balance Start  Balance End  Difference
0            MASTER         701.00       701.00        0.00
0               NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN
1   Algemeen/*!%@!#        2240.25      2181.45      -58.80
9         120989894           0.00         0.00        0.00
5         159142752           0.00         0.00        0.00
4         286695535         300.00       300.00        0.00
12        578951057          30.00        30.00        0.00
13        706602827           0.00         0.00        0.00
2         735592139           0.00         0.00        0.00
11        810226753         250.00       229.16      -20.84
3         811695012           0.00         0.00        0.00
6         818329167          22.85        22.85        0.00
0               NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN
2           General        3913.56      3813.56     -100.00
8         138738399          42.79        27.79      -15.00
0         646746507           0.00         0.00        0.00
1         767402418           2.90         2.90        0.00
10        948214665         545.07       391.57     -153.50
7         A98744534         461.32        75.36     -385.96
0               NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN
0            Totals        8509.74      7775.64     -734.10
```

I want to fetch the account name and cards in separate columns. such as "Master", "Algemeen/*!%@!#", "GENERAL". I tried to get it by using groupby but that doesnt work for me.

```
for date, new_df in balances.groupby(level=0):
    print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code for this issue, but it's good if you define expected output as well (I use apply function to check every value if its length is 9 or not)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./stackoverflowacctcard.csv')
def collect_card(acct_card):
    if len(str(acct_card)) != 9:
        return acct_card
    else:
        return ''
def collect_account(acct_card):
    if len(str(acct_card)) == 9:
        return acct_card
    else:
        ''
df['Card'] = df['Account / Card'].apply(collect_card)
df['Account'] = df['Account / Card'].apply(collect_account)
df.drop('Account / Card', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bro. 
But i created a separate column with CARD and ACCOUNT type for these two specific keywords. Then i calculated the sum by using the groupby Card or Account.
`
accounts_start_end_balance["Card_Account_Type"] = "ACCOUNT"
`